# Z-axis window value

Tags: windows, winapi

I can retrieve the position of window using `GetWindowRect` winapi function.

It should be a function also that defines the order of windows in z-axis (which window is above and which is under), but cannot find the appropriate function.

Point me to any one?

Comment: @In silico: yep, I have their hwnds and I need to get their positional relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get the z order directly. You are expected to call `GetWindow()`passing `GW_HWNDNEXT` or `GW_HWNDPREV` to walk the z order hierarchy.

Start at one of your windows and walk until you find either the other window or your walk terminates. This then tells you the relationship between the two windows.

Comment: Yep. My answer looks slightly better in my case though.

Comment: yes, there are many ways to skin a cat as they say. Thanks for the rep!!

Comment: don't like to keep opened questions I've got answers to ;-) So, thanks for your answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, seems like `EnumDesktopWindows` returns windows in the Z order from the top to the bottom. So no need in any special function then (which doesn't exist perhaps).